# Time data doesn't match format (Oura API)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I try to access my Oura ring data and try to play around a bit with it to practice my python. The documentation is [here](https://python-ouraring.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

When I try to get the readiness_df I have no issue with the date. The same date for the combined_df gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\stefa\OneDrive\Coding\Oura\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    combined_df = client.combined_df_edited(start=start)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oura\client_pandas.py", line 198, in combined_df_edited
    sleep_df = self.sleep_df(start, end, metrics)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oura\client_pandas.py", line 104, in sleep_df
    return SleepConverter(convert_cols).convert_metrics(df)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oura\converters.py", line 119, in convert_metrics
    df = super().convert_metrics(df)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oura\converters.py", line 86, in convert_metrics
    df = self._convert_to_dt(df, dt_metrics)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oura\converters.py", line 57, in _convert_to_dt
    df[dt_metric] = pd.to_datetime(df[dt_metric], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 1050, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 453, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    return _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, utc, format, exact, errors)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 484, in _array_strptime_with_fallback
    result, timezones = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors, utc=utc)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 530, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 351, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data "2018-11-15T08:02:30+01:00" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", at position 0. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.
```

I don't understand why, according to the documentation, the date format is correct. Also, the code runs without any errors in Spyder.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
from oura import OuraClientDataFrame
from api_token import API_TOKEN

oura_token = API_TOKEN # Your Oura token
client = OuraClientDataFrame(personal_access_token=oura_token) # Make connection

# Check you the connection is working and you have access to your account
who_am_i_df = client.user_info_df()
print(who_am_i_df)

start = '2018-11-01'
days = 7
week_past = str(date.today() - timedelta(days))
#######

# Pull readiness data and combined features into separate dataframes
# Start is set to beginning of 01-NOV-2018 -> earliest available months for me
readiness_df = client.readiness_df(start=start)
print(readiness_df.head())
combined_df = client.combined_df_edited(start=start)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: It's not the problem with `start`, but with the data they try to process. Note  that error is with `"2018-11-15T08:02:30+01:00"` not matching format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` which is true. It may well be change in the API (data returned in different format).

Comment: @buran you're right. I checked a few different dates and it happens on different occasions. readiness_df works fin, combined_df keeps having a problem with a date in the selected range. Any ideas how to catch that or why it works in Sypder without errors?